# Where can I find the documentation for the Linux NPU API?

Tags: linux, documentation, api

For example the [Samsung Galaxy S10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S10) has an [Exynos 9820](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exynos) CPU with integrated NPU. We all know Android is based on Linux.

So where can I find the Linux API documentation about how to interact with the NPU?

For example there must be a way to get the frequency and core count of the NPU. Maybe they are listed in `/proc/cpuinfo`? Also I want to load a program into the NPU and execute it.

All this must be documented somewhere. Where can I find the Linux NPU documentation?

I already know where to find the Android AI documentation. But I am looking for the Linux NPU documentation which is on a lower level.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for actually exists.

Comment: I.e. what indication do you have this is actually a standardized Linux subsystem and not just some random device hanging of some bus, probably AMBA, which Linux has essentially nothing to do with but maybe setting up a memory mapping?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok so there is no such Linux API and it must be an proprietary API on the Galaxy S10. Thank you for your help.